# Upload shapefile to ArcGIS Server, using Python API

Tags: arcgis-server

I have shapefiles (.zip) that I want to upload to an ArcGIS Server programmatically using the [ArcGIS Python API](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/).

All the examples I've found assume the data is already on the server. Is there a tutorial on uploading data to the server using the Python library?

Comment: ArcGIS Server doesn't accept data uploads (unless you write a service). Do you want to load the data into an Enterprise geodatabase? Or to load the data into a hosted feature service in Portal?  If the latter, that's something the Python API can do.

Comment: I think what I want is to load it as a hosted feature service in Portal.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to focus on Portal and/or Enterprise, instead of Server (but first, since it's a programming question, take some time to research the topic and include your code).  You should specify the version of ArcGIS Server in use.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific workflow? As for the hosted feature service, unless the data is really small, I'd recommend you use filegeodatabase or enterprise geodatabase, not shapefile.